# Ajax not post checked

Tags: ajax

i have a problem with post ajax ajax.

Values send - `var asc = $("#auth_site_check").val();`

And how send cheked? -  `var asc = $("#auth_site_check").check();`

Sorry for my English, i don`t know English well. (I am from Russia =)  )

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

On checkbox click post event fire.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chkbx" value="cbval"/>



$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#chkbx").click(function(){
    var request = $.ajax({
                    url: ..., //access method url
                    type: 'POST',
                    cache: false,
                    data: { ParameterValue: $("#chkbx").val() } ,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
                        });
             });        
    });
```

Comment: Sorry, but i don`t know how set your code to this
function auth(){
var email = $("#auth_site_mail").val();
var pass = $("#auth_site_pass").val();
var result = document.getElementById('result');
$.ajax({
url: "script/auth.php",
type: "POST",
data:{email: email,pass: pass}, 
success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
result.innerHTML = '<div class="ininar">'+data+'</div>';
}
});
}

Comment: So what you want? you do not pass check box value?